# GDPR Consent form crashing: WindowManager BadTokenException

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context, android-windowmanager

I am showing [Google's GDPR consent form](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eu-consent) and I am noticing a lot of these reports:

```
Fatal Exception: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException
Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@38734f2 is not valid; is your activity running?
com.my.project.MainActivity$4.onConsentFormLoaded
```

As context I use `MainActivity.this`:

```
private void displayConsentForm() {
    consentForm = new ConsentForm.Builder(MainActivity.this, GeneralUtils.getAppsPrivacyPolicy())
            .withListener(new ConsentFormListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConsentFormLoaded() {
                    consentForm.show(); // crashing here for some users
                }

                @Override
                public void onConsentFormOpened() { }

                @Override
                public void onConsentFormClosed(
                    ConsentStatus consentStatus, Boolean userPrefersAdFree) {

                    if(userPrefersAdFree) {
                            ConsentInformation.getInstance(MainActivity.this)
                                    .setConsentStatus(NON_PERSONALIZED);
                    } else {
                        ConsentInformation.getInstance(MainActivity.this)
                                .setConsentStatus(consentStatus);
                    }

                    initAds();
                }

                @Override
                public void onConsentFormError(String errorDescription) {
                    Log.e("Error",errorDescription);
                }
            })
            .withPersonalizedAdsOption()
            .withNonPersonalizedAdsOption()
            .withAdFreeOption()
            .build();

    consentForm.load();
}
```

Here is additional Firebase crash report:

[image]

Why is this happening and how to prevent it? I am not sure what additional check to put before `consentForm.show()` and I can not reproduce the issue. Maybe it would suffice if I put this check before showing the form:

```
if(!MainActivity.this.isFinishing() && !MainActivity.this.isDestroyed())
```

?

Comment: The common case for this occurring is trying to show a dialog after the activity begins finishing.  Generally I just catch and ignore the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way around this would be to just put a try-catch block around `consentForm.show()` and catch the BadTokenException.

It's not really clean, but it's likely that this is happening when the Activity finishes (maybe the user closes the app from Recents right as the Dialog is loading).

If this were my project, I'd first try adding that if statement you have (although you don't need the `MainActivity.this.` part; you can just call `isFinishing()` and `isDestroyed()` directly). Since you're referencing an Activity Context, this should take care of it.

However, if it still crashes, you should first look into reproducing it. Try getting to just before `displayConsentForm()` is called, then closing the app from Recents. Play around with the timing and you'll probably reproduce the crash. If not, then just add the try-catch. The Activity isn't displayed, since it's throwing that error, so the user isn't actually in the app.

Comment: Thank you. This means the crash is not critical, which makes my mind a bit more at peace. I will add the additional measures as discussed.